# Is a CiviVolunteer shortcode available?

Tags: civivolunteer

All my WordPress pages have completely different headers (through a plugin). However, I need to get the `Search for Volunteer Opportunities` form in CiviVolunteer to appear on a WordPress page in order to change its header.

Is there a shortcode to do this? If this is not possible, how would I go about giving the form its own header?

Comment: Still unable to accomplish above. Also, no Volunteer Opportunities form shows up for non-logged-in users, even though the have the proper permissions. Only a header, footer, sidebar, and nothing in between.

I tried the clean URL's suggestion below, but, it doesn't allow me to place Volunteer Opportunities on an actual WordPress page.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not a shortcode available, but I'm not sure either that it isn't trivial to enable one.

But, I suspect it is not necessary for what you are trying to acomplish.

Have you enabled clean URL's for your CiviCRM install?

https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/wordpress/#enabling-cleaner-urls-for-wordpress

After you do that, the sign-up page should be displayed with your wordpress front-end theme: http://example.org/civicrm/vol/#/volunteer/opportunities

Be sure to note the permissions required: https://docs.civicrm.org/volunteer/en/latest/sign-up-form/

I think this would enable your custom plugin to display its headers.

Saludos!

Comment: I just implemented the cleaner URLs, checked permissions, cleared caches. Header shows up fine as you expected.

However, now, for the Available Volunteer Opportunities page, I only have a header and a footer (and a sidebar). No Volunteer Opportunities form.

I can see the form, complete with headers and footers only when I'm signed in to WordPress.

Comment: If it looks right when you are signed in, that sounds like a permissions issue. I would confirm the access Ajax API permission.

Comment: Permissions were confirmed. I read somewhere else that the http://example.org/civicrm/vol/#/volunteer/opportunities url is for Drupal. I am using WordPress 5.3.2 with CiviCRM 5.22.1.